# Is there a standard name for this probability-theoretic construction?

Tags: probability-theory, terminology

What follows is a description of a concept in probability theory that I find very useful, but cannot find described in the literature. I've been calling it the "perplectic sum", but that's a term I made up. The idea seems fundamental enough that I can't be the first one to have thought of it, and I'd like to know if it has a standard name and/or notation.

Let $A = (\Omega_A, \mathcal F_A, P_A)$, $B = (\Omega_B, \mathcal F_B, P_B)$ be two probability spaces. Let $PP$ denote perplexity, i.e., $PP(A) = e^{H(A)}$ where $H(A)$ is the entropy of $A$ measured in nats. Then the perplectic sum $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P) = A \oplus_{PP} B$ is defined as follows:

- $\Omega$ = $\Omega_A \sqcup \Omega_B$, i.e. the disjoint union (categorical coproduct) of $\Omega_A$ and $\Omega_B$.
- $\mathcal F = \mathcal F_A \times \mathcal F_B$.
- $P((X,Y))$ = $P_A(X) \cdot \frac{PP(A)}{PP(A)+PP(B)}$ + $P_B(Y) \cdot \frac{PP(B)}{PP(A)+PP(B)}$.

Trivial example: if $P_A$ is defined by the discrete uniform distribution over the set $\{1,2\}$ and $P_B$ is defined by the discrete uniform distribution over the set $\{3,4,5,6\}$, then $P$ is defined by the discrete uniform distribution over the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: I do not understand how $\mathcal F$ is a sigma-algebra on $\Omega$ nor how $P$ is a probability on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ (assuming $\mathcal F$ is a sigma-algebra on $\Omega$).

Comment: You're right: I think the definition as it stands doesn't satisfy the required closure properties of a σ-algebra; I'll update it as soon as I've figured out the required correction.

Comment: Okay, updated. $\mathcal F$ is a product, not a coproduct.

Comment: And? Note that the (set-) product of two sigma-algebras is not a sigma-algebra in general. At this point, it might be worthwhile to read and ponder some construction of the product of two measured spaces and see how what you have in mind differ from it. Finally, if you are not MO user Łukasz Grabowski, [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51488/which-categorical-coproduct-like-operation-captures-integration-of-measures) might interest you.

Comment: Maybe if I explain the intuition behind the definition then you'll be able to point out where my formalism is going astray. Suppose I have two bags each containing a finite number of objects. Some objects are bigger than others, so if I reach into a bag and grab an object without looking, some will be more likely than others to come out. Then the perplectic sum is intended to be the operation of dumping all the objects into a single bag.  I want to generalize this idea to infinite sample spaces, using perplexity to give rigor to the notion of "size", and keep the operation associative.

Comment: I just came across this paper which defines a construction similar to mine: 
http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Lynn.pdf, except that it weights the two cofactors equally rather than according to their respective perplexity, making a remark that the choice of weighting scheme is irrelevant up to isomorphism of categories (considering the category $\mathrm{Prob}$, defined therein).

Comment: I think I finally understand what you mean. See answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you have in mind is the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ defined by $\Omega=\Omega_A\cup\Omega_B$ under the condition that $\Omega_A\cap\Omega_B=\varnothing$, by $\mathcal F=\{C\cup D\mid C\in\mathcal F_A,D\in\mathcal F_B\}$ (hence, definitely not the definition that you wrote), and by $P(C\cup D)=tP_A(C)+(1-t)P_B(D)$ for every $C$ in $\mathcal F_A$ and $D$ in $\mathcal F_B$.

To make sense of this definition, one should note that each $F$ in $\mathcal F$ can be written *uniquely* as $F=C\cup D$ with $C$ in $\mathcal F_A$ and $D$ in $\mathcal F_B$ (namely, consider $C=F\cap\Omega_A$ and $D=F\cap\Omega_B$).

In the "Trivial example" at the end of your post, this yields any probability measure $P$ on $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that $P(\{1\})=P(\{2\})$ and such that $P(\{3\})=P(\{4\})=P(\{5\})=P(\{6\})$ (but not necessarily the uniform distribution).

My guess is that most people, when faced with this construction and asked for a name, would call it (admittedly rather loosely) a *disjoint union of probability spaces* (and they would explain the meaning of the phrase right away).

Finally, a caveat is in order at this point: an example or two of results which the constructions in the paper you mention in  comment, allow to reach, would be useful to estimate the worthiness of the whole enterprise (the paper in question (admittedly preliminary) seems to give none).

Comment: The definition you've stated is consistent with what I had in mind. I guess you're correct that even when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint $A \times B$ is not the same set as $\left\{C\cup D \mid C \in A, D \in B\right\}$, but they're the same up to the obvious isomorphism in which all operations supported by a $\sigma$-algebra are mapped componentwise. Sorry if I caused confusion by handwaving over the distinction. Anyway, I believe the second part of your post answers my question: there is a not notation for this, at least not one sufficiently standard that it can be used without defining it first.

Comment: And what about the last paragraph of my answer?

Comment: The application which inspired this construction is random generation of payloads for black-box fuzz testing of network protocols (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing).  The general idea is that if you have message generators for two disjoint subsets of some language, then the perplectic sum is, in some sense that I'm still trying to pin down, the "natural" or "optimal" way of combining them.

Comment: I am not sure to understand: tons of people are already studying that, trying to solve fearful practical and theoretical problems to which the notion of category seems quite unrelated. Anyway... thanks for the comment.